# Possibility of changing the plaintext modulus after encryption in homomorphic schemes like BGV

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm working on a project with two computation "phases". In the first phase, I would like to homomorphically compute operations on my ciphertexts with a plaintext modulus of 2. But for my second phase, I would like to use a different plaintext modulus say 12799.
Without decrypting and reencrypting my results between phase 1 and 2, is it possible to change the plaintext modulus after I have encrypted my ciphertexts?

Thank you for any help!